# How to make DNN learn multiplication/division?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, feedforward-neural-networks

A single neuron with **2 weights and identity activation** can learn addition/subtraction as the 2 weights will converge to **1 and 1** (addition), or **1 and -1** (subtraction).

However, for **multiplication** and **division**, it's not that easy. Can a single neuron learn multiplication or division? If not, how many layers of DNN can learn these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reallity any continous function on a compact can be approximated by a neural network having one hidden layer with a finite number of neurones (This is the [Universal Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)). Thus you only need one hidden layer to approximate the multiplication on a compact, note that you need to apply a non linear activation on the hidden layer to do this.

Comment: A Neural network cannot approximate an unbounded function.

Comment: All functions are bounded on a compact